# Android screen orientation detection without layout change

Tags: android, orientation

I want to detect layout change in my activity while keeping the widgets where they are. Is there any way to do this. I tried setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL) and it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add  `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your manifest file in the activity and you may be able to get the orientation in the onResume method of your activity by using

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
//WHAT TO DO IN LANDSCAPE
} else {
//WHAT TO DO IN PORTRAIT
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a lower level solution, you could use one of the [Sensors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html), to detect the orientation/tilt of the device. If you don't want layout changes you can constraint your activity to portrait or landscape only in the manifest...

You can play with the app [Elixir](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bt.android.elixir&hl=en) to see what values a specific sensor returns.

Comment: I tried constraining the orientation in the manifest file. My activity is actually camera activity from which I'll be retrieving an image. When I do so, I want to retain its orientation. This seems to be well implemented in the native camera app of the phone. I was just wondering if that was easy to do. :)

Comment: Yup, playing with the sensors and extracting the orientation information from those values would surely req a few hours of work. Look around, there might be a library for extracting that info. (If not yet supported by an API call)